# How to send post request for related data from angular to .NET core api

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm new to angular and .NET core, I'm trying to store related data to sqlserver via .net core api.
My problem is Order controller is receiving one Order object how It will store orderitems with same OrderId which will be generated in Order Table? Plus I'm unable to call order controller, my service method returning this error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
>   POST https://localhost:44378/api/Orders 500

**checkout.ts**

```
  placeorder() {

    this.postservice.placeorder(this.orderdata.value, this.cart.selections)
  }
```

In this code *orderdata.value* are simple values while *cart.selections* are list of objects

**Service code**

```
  placeorder(orderdata: order, orderitems: orderItems): Observable<any[]>{
return this.http.post<any[]>(this.myAppUrl + 'api/Orders', [orderdata,orderitems]);}
```

**order Interface**

```
export interface order{
  orderid: number;
  uid: number;
  orderdate: Date;
  orderstatus: string;

}
```

**OrderItems interface**

```
export interface orderItems extends Array<orderItem> {
}

export interface orderItem {
  productId?: number;
  productName?: string;
  productPrice?: number;
  quantityValue?: number;
}
```

**Order Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Orders>> PostOrders(Orders orders)
{
  _context.Orders.Add(orders);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

   return CreatedAtAction("GetOrders", new { id = orders.OrderId }, orders);
 }
```

**Order Model Class**

```
    public partial class Orders
{
    public Orders()
    {
        OrderItems = new HashSet<OrderItems>();
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int? Uid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string OrderStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrderItems> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
```

**OrderItems Model Class**

```
public partial class OrderItems
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int? ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int? ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public int? ProductQuantity { get; set; }
    public int? OrderId { get; set; }

    public virtual Orders Order { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your request correctly, you would like to add articles related to an order that does not yet exist. In technical terms, you do not have the primary order key to indicate it as a foreign key on the articles.

When you add an entry in your DbContext and make a backup of this DbContext, the unique identifier is valued and returned to you on the previously added object.

If you add an "Order" object in your DbContext you cannot indicate the unique identifier there because SQL will take care of it. If you make a DbContext.SaveChanges(), know that the unique identifier of the order will be valued on the instance of the "Order" object previously added to your DbContext.

You just have to add the articles in your database with the unique identifier of the order.

I remain available if you have any questions, see you soon!

Comment: OrderId is a primary key in Order Table and OrderId in OrderItems is a foreign key, I know when I add an entry it will return the entry that is added, But what I want is to send both order and orderitems table values and it should auto setup primary key in order table and same key value as foreign key in orderitems table.